# is there a plugin for VS2008 that makes it use normal regexs for find/replace?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008

Re: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000633.html

Is there a plugin that turns VS2008's non-standard regex find/replace into a more standard version? I didn't find one when I googled for it, so my hopes are not high for this. I hate hate hate having to build a regex in my head and then have to think, "oh, I guess I need to refactor that for VS2008".

> It is a very oddball regex syntax, and as best we can tell it comes from Visual C++ 2.0. We did want to add additional support for .NET 2.0-style regular expressions in the Visual Studio 2005 release, but unfortunately due to time pressures it didn't make the final list of features. We were able to make a number of bug fixes to the existing engine though, to give some improvement over VS 2003.
>
> ...
>
> Neil Enns Lead Program Manager
>   Microsoft Visual Studio

^^ Yeesh. That post by Neil was dated 2006.

Comment: If anyone is curious, I didn't find it on google because I was looking for "plugin" instead of "addin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else linked this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/VS2008RegexAddIn.aspx but the answer disappeared. I'll delete this if it comes back. I did install that add in, it works so far...